# Combining Two Flows and add them to temporary list of StateFlow(Hot Flows)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-stateflow

I m getting data from two End points using flows and assigning those two list to temporary list in ViewModel. For this purpose, I'm using combine function and returning result as **stateFlows** with **stateIn** operator but that's not working. Can anyone point me out where I go wrong please.

> ViewModel.kt

```
private val _movieItem: MutableStateFlow<State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems>>> =
        MutableStateFlow(State.Loading())
val movieItems: StateFlow<State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems>>> = _movieItem

fun getHomeItemList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
        val testList: Flow<State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Movie>>> =
                settingsRepo.getMovieList().map {
                    State.fromResource(it)
                }
        val directorList: Flow<State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Directors>>> =
                settingsRepo.getDirectorList().map {
                    State.fromResource(it)
                }
        _movieItem.value = combine(testList, directorList) { testList, directorList ->
                  testList + directorList // This is not working as "+" Unresolve Error
             }.stateIn(
                 viewModelScope,
                 SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                 State.loading<Nothing>()
             ) as State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems>> // Unchecked cast: StateFlow<Any> to State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems>>
}
```

> Repository.kt

```
fun getMovieList(): Flow<ResponseAPI<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Movie>>> {
        return object :
            NetworkBoundRepository<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Movie>, List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Movie>>() {
            override suspend fun saveRemoteData(response: List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Movie>) {

            }

            override fun fetchFromLocal() {
            }

            override suspend fun fetchFromRemote(): Response<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Movie>> =
                apiInterface.getMoviesList()
        }.asFlow()
    }

    fun getDirectorList(): Flow<ResponseAPI<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Directors>>> {
        return object :
            NetworkBoundRepository<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Directors>, List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Directors>>() {
            override suspend fun saveRemoteData(response: List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Directors>) {

            }

            override fun fetchFromLocal() {
            }

            override suspend fun fetchFromRemote(): Response<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Directors>> =
                apiInterface.getDirectorsList()

        }.asFlow()
    }
```

> Network BoundRepository.kt

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
abstract class NetworkBoundRepository<RESULT, REQUEST> {

    fun asFlow() = flow<ResponseAPI<REQUEST>> {

        val apiResponse = fetchFromRemote()

        val remotePosts = apiResponse.body()

        
        if (apiResponse.isSuccessful && remotePosts != null) {
          
            emit(ResponseAPI.Success(remotePosts))
        } else {
            emit(ResponseAPI.Failed(apiResponse.errorBody()!!.string()))
        }

    }.catch { e ->
        e.printStackTrace()
        emit(ResponseAPI.Failed("Server Problem! Please try again Later. "))
    }

    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract suspend fun saveRemoteData(response: REQUEST)

    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun fetchFromLocal()

    @MainThread
    protected abstract suspend fun fetchFromRemote(): Response<REQUEST>
}
```

> Endpoints with Sealed Class

```
@GET("directors")
        fun getDirectorsList(): Response<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Directors>>
@GET("movies")
    fun getMoviesList(): Response<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Movie>>
sealed class HomeRecyclerViewItems {
    class Title(
        val id: Int,
        val title: String
        ) : HomeRecyclerViewItems()

    class Movie(
        val id: Int,
        val title: String,
        val thumbnail: String,
        val releaseDate: String
    ) : HomeRecyclerViewItems()

    class Directors(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val avator: String,
        val movie_count: Int
    ) : HomeRecyclerViewItems()
}
```

> Fragment.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class SettingsFragment : BaseBottomTabFragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentSettingsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val viewModel by viewModels<SettingViewModel>()
    @Inject
    lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerViewAdapter
   @Inject
   lateinit var bundle: Bundle
    var finalList = mutableListOf<HomeRecyclerViewItems>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
        val view = binding.root
        binding.rvMovie.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        }
                bundle.putString("Hello","hihg")
        Toast.makeText(activity, "${bundle.getString("Hello")}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        finalList.add(HomeRecyclerViewItems.Title(1,"hello"))



        return view
    }

    private fun observeList() {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                launch {
                    viewModel.movieItems.collect { state ->
                        when(state){
                            is State.Loading ->{
                               
                            }
                            is State.Success->{
                                if (state.data.isNotEmpty()){
                                    recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter()
                                    binding.rvMovie.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
                                    recyclerViewAdapter.submitList(finalList)
                                }
                            }
                            is State.Error -> {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                            else -> Unit
                        }

                    }
                }
               
            }
        }
    }



    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (activity as MainActivity).binding.ivSearch.isGone = true
        viewModel.getHomeItemList()
        observeList()
    }
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Note: I m following this tutorial [simpliedCoding](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/kotlin-recyclerview-example/) for api data for multirecyclerview but want to implement it with Kotlin State Flow. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in here

```
val testList: Flow<State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Movie>>> =
                settingsRepo.getMovieList().map {
                    State.fromResource(it)
                }
val directorList: Flow<State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems.Directors>>> =
                settingsRepo.getDirectorList().map {
                    State.fromResource(it)
                }
_movieItem.value = combine(testList, directorList) { testList, directorList ->
                  testList + directorList
             }
```

They are not returning a `List<HomeRecyclerViewItems>`, but a `State<List<HomeRecyclerViewItems>`. Maybe a better name for the variables are `testsState` and `directorsState`. After that it will be more clear why you need to unpack the values before combining the lists

```
_movieItem.value = combine(testsState, directorsState) { testsState, directorsState ->
                  val homeRecyclerViewItems = mutableListOf<HomeRecyclerViewItems>()
                  if (testsState is Success) homeRecyclerViewItems.add(testsState.data)
                  if (directorsState is Success) homeRecyclerViewItems.add(directorsState.data)
                  homeRecyclerViewItems
             }
```